# SQL Server Table and Type names are same

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need a lot of pairs of a table and a type with the same structure (for table valued parameters). While thinking of proper naming convention I accidentally created both: table and type, having the same name. I.e. I have table A(x int) and type A(x int).

So... am I doing something wrong? It seems that table and type can be distinguished and there is no place in T-SQL where you can use "type or table", so code will not be ambiguous, but I'm a little afraid of using something, that can be bad practice and need an advice.

Comment: I wouldn't do anything that might cause confusion for the next person who has to read your code.

Comment: You *can* use `[type]` and `[table]`, etc, to avoid problems of using reserved keywords.  But as above, it creates confusion, mistakes and is generally just a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not wrong, but it can be frowned upon by others who may tap into your code or take over the schema.  Model it so that they aren't exactly the same even though in your mind they could be.  Easier said then done, but follow that and be consistent with it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't really mean `A`. It isn't the 70s anymore, there is no reason to create such obfuscated and meaningless names. I'm sure that's not what you really called your type and table, but I wanted to mention it just in case.

If you need to differentiate between a real table and a TVP that represents the exact same structure and entity, there really isn't a problem with that, but you could always recreate your type as `dbo.TableName_TVP` or `dbo.TVP_TableName` - and use this convention consistently. This way when someone comes across code that references one or the other, the TVP reference stands out (since TVP references are hopefully going to be far less common in your code than references to base tables).

Comment: OMG, of course "A" was just for example and it is not a real name.

Comment: That's what I assumed, but like I said, *I wanted to mention it just in case.*